# Misplaced frametitle in new environment

Tags: beamer, environments, frame-title

In beamer, I defined a new environment for frame. My problem is, the frame title now comes along the text, instead of appearing at the top. See the working example.

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle}
\usepackage{environ} 
\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{%
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{#1}
\BODY
\end{frame}}
\begin{document}
\begin{myframe}{TITLE}
comes here !
\end{myframe}
\end{document}
```

Can anybody help ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Remove the `[]` after `[1]`, which is declaring that the argument to `\begin{myframe}` is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{...}` you are declaring that `myframe` has an optional argument (default empty), so when you use

```
\begin{myframe}{TITLE}
```

the value of `#1` is empty. The title is there, but it's empty. You can prove it by changing

```
\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][]{%
```

into

```
\NewEnviron{myframe}[1][Hey!]{%
```

and you'll see “Hey!” in the title place.

You should remove `[]`:

```
\NewEnviron{myframe}[1]{%
\begin{frame}[noframenumbering]{#1}
\BODY
\end{frame}}
```

or, with your definition, calling the environment as

```
\begin{myframe}[TITLE]
```

Comment: That worked perfectly Egreg ! Now I can present my slides with headers. Today  only I understood what is happening in the background.  

Thank you very much for your effort.